# Paragraph positioning in a parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a comp to code up and this one particular area is turning out to be a real pain. If you look at the comp you can see that the first and last lines of the text lay about 50% outside of the container.

[image]

I can achieve this using exact math in the CSS, but as you can imagine as the text wraps on different browser sizes the math needs to change in order to keep the design intact. This can quickly become a media query nightmare.

Is there a better way to achieve this effect while keeping the design intact as the browser resizes?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 190px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -10%;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quo voluptatibus enim doloremque ab illum nam consequuntur nihil, vel magni ipsa maxime numquam odio explicabo!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm thinking you should be able to do this, just need to use -.5em on top and bottom?  trying to work it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get it to work in the snippet, but here is what I have working locally.

uses `::before` though...

css:

```
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }

    .container {
        width: 500px;
        height: 190px;
        padding: 0 50px;
    }

    p {
        color: white;
        /* background-color: green; */
        position: relative;
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 1.15;
    }

        p::before {
            content: ' ';
            background-color: gray;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0.5em;
            bottom: 0.5em;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            font-size: 32px;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quo voluptatibus enim doloremque ab illum nam consequuntur nihil, vel magni ipsa maxime numquam odio explicabo!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. It never once crossed my mind to consider using ::before in this manner, and it makes complete sense why this works. Thanks!

Comment: I've been using it a bit every now and then and ::before and ::after seem to come in really handy for simple additions like this.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to resize with the browser window using absolute positioning.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
  right:30px;
  top:30px;
  bottom:30px;
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  font-size:30px;
  top:-50px;
  bottom:-50px;
  right:50px;
  left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quo voluptatibus enim doloremque ab illum nam consequuntur nihil, vel magni ipsa maxime numquam odio explicabo!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Trust me that would make this a lot easier, but I would lose the effect of the first and last lines of the text hanging outside of the parent

Comment: close, this is a result I came up with before posting. Definitely helps with the first line but the last line of text is still variable. I was able to get an answer though

Answer (score 0):

Just add   `margin:0; padding:0; position:absolute` to p, and `overflow:auto;` to .container to be able to scroll if you increased the p content.

[Codepin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrjgP)

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 190px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  background-color: #444;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}

p {
  color: white;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color: #777;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. quo vptatibus enim doloremque ab illum nam equuntur, vel magni ipsa maxime numquam odio explicabo!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the input but I think you misunderstood the question. I was able to get an answer

Comment: My bad! i thought the pic is your problem! but why you want that? just nosiness

Comment: I dont, but the client does!